# Difference between ${pom.basedir} vs ${project.basedir} in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml, system-paths

Getting below warning while build.

I am using  in pom.xml

```
<systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/....jar</systemPath>
```

> [WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for ...:jar should not
> point at files within the project directory,
> ${project.basedir}/lib/....jar will be unresolvable by dependent
> projects @ line 25, column 30

Its resolved now by using `<systemPath>${pom.basedir}/lib`/....jar in pom.xml

Anyone please explain, What is difference between ${pom.basedir} vs ${project.basedir} in pom.xml?

Comment: Do not use systemPath at all... Use a repository manager ...You should not use any property like `${pom.*} anymore ...

Comment: @khmarbaise I am planning to use local repository only, But my doubt is how its working without warning by using ${pom.basedir} not in {project.basedir}.

Comment: Use local repository only? With system path?

Comment: Local repository only? How to get artifacts into that?

Comment: @khmarbaise   My question is not relevant to repository manager.. My actual question is earlier when I am using System path as ${project.basedir} I got warning message (Please refer above),. but I didn't see any warning after using System path as ${pom.basedir}.. So What is different here project.basedir vs pom.basedir?

Comment: It is relevatn related to repository manager because if you would use one you don't have to use systemPath...

Comment: @khmarbaise  You understood wrongly, My question is before implementing repository manager.

Comment: 1. `pom.basedir` is deprecated and should not be used anymore. 2. Systempath should be avoided if at all possible.

Answer (score 2):

`${basedir}`, `${project.basedir}` and `${pom.basedir}` [are synonyms](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.6/maven-model-builder/#model-interpolation) (you may also check that using something like `mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=pom.basedir`), your Q just reveals that person who was fixing [MNG-4953](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4953) didn't know about that.